# How to give Record Id in url in a lightning app like a VF page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, record

I'm a newbie.
I want to know that how can I provide a recorid in the url and manipulate the record in lightning component like I do in vf pages.?
Can anybody help please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an event called [**force:navigateToSObject**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm)

You can go to detail page of the record by providing its Id.

Answer (score 1):

The analogous feature in lightning is [URL-Centric Navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/url_nav.htm).

Using the following as an example:

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="theId" type="Id" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="c.handleLocationChange"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.theId}" />
</aura:application>

({
    handleLocationChange : function (component, event, helper) {
        var loc = event.getParam("token");
        console.log(loc);
        component.set("{!v.theId}",loc);
    }

})
```

When you navigate to your lightning application, the fragment portion of the url after the `#`, will be captured in the `token` parameter of the `aura:locationChange` event.

A sample url would look something like this:

```
<baseurl>/<YourApplicationName>.app#ASampleId
```

Comment: Can I do the same with <aura:component></aura:component> tags or this only works with <aura:application> tags?

Comment: @AnnJanu I suppose you could use it with an `<aura:component>` if it is a persistent component in your own application, but it won't work for components that are dynamically created (including components in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 flexipages).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm

Now you can build components for record home pages!

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
```

And also you can specify the sobject type:

```
<aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
```